# Как удалить не нужные строки прочитанные из файла по частям?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть .txt список в таком виде:

```
vasya:true12
gena:false9999
petya:true888
oleg:falsetrue
fan:falsetrue909
```

Нужно удалить всю строку, в которой после двоеточия слово не содержит букву, либо не содержит цифру, либо длина меньше 8 символов.

Для приведенных выше данных, результат должен быть такой:

```
gena:false9999
fan:falsetrue909
```

Список очень большой, потому важна скорость работы. И метод читать файл построчно не подходит, т.к. это долго.

Решил использовать Pandas, чтобы читать файл частями, а именно:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

file = 'test.txt'
chunker = pd.read_table(file,chunksize=10000)
for chunk in chunker:
    print(chunk)
```

Но вот как из каждой части удалить не нужные строки, не знаю.

Comment: вообще grep-ом из консоли решается на раз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1:**

```
chunksize = 10000
min_len = 8
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=":", header=None, 
                     names=["name", "pwd"], chunksize=chunksize)
for df in reader:
    mask = df["pwd"].str.contains("\d") & df["pwd"].str.contains("\w") & df["pwd"].str.len().ge(min_len)
    # process matched rows
    print(df.loc[mask])
```

Пример работы:

```
In [24]: df.loc[mask]
Out[24]:
   name           pwd
1  gena     false9999
4   fan  falsetrue909
```

---

**Вариант 2:**  (используем регулярки, но не используем медленные `look ahead` и `look behind`):

```
chunksize = 10000
min_len = 8
reader = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=":", header=None, 
                     names=["name", "pwd"], chunksize=chunksize)
for df in reader:
    mask = ~df["pwd"].str.contains(r"^(?:.{0,7}|\D+|[^\W\d_]+)$")
    # -----^    <----- инвертирование маски - чтобы выбрать строки, НЕ удовлятворяющие RegEx
    # process matched rows
    print(df.loc[~mask])
```

---

Замеры времени для 50.000 строк:

```
In [47]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [48]: df.shape
Out[48]: (50000, 2)

In [60]: %timeit ~df["pwd"].str.contains(r"^(?:.{0,7}|\D+|[^\W\d_]+)$")
64.4 ms ± 1.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [61]: %timeit df["pwd"].str.contains("\d") & df["pwd"].str.contains("\w") & df["pwd"].str.len().ge(min_len)
99.9 ms ± 5.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

PS хотел добавить для сравнения времени выполнения [вариант от @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187805/211923), но не смог преобразовать его RegEx в такой, чтобы он правильно работал в Python... :(

Comment: строку qqq:01234567890 не должно парсить  ) 
не могли бы вы исправить код и измерить еще скорость работы вариант от @Qwertiy . Спасибо )

Comment: и qqq,01234567890 принтит через , , а хотелось бы через :
Использую Вариант 2

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж метка [регулярные-выражения](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f), то вот.
Но вообще-то надо просто читать файл и сразу его парсить и обрабатывать.

```js
console.log(`vasya:true12
gena:false9999
petya:true888
oleg:falsetrue
fan:falsetrue909
qqq:01234567890`
.replace(/^.*:(.{0,7}|((?!.*(?!\d)\w)|(?!.*\d)).*)\r?$\n?/gm, ""))
```

Опитонил: https://ideone.com/dHFc8g

```
import re

s = """vasya:true12
gena:false9999
petya:true888
oleg:falsetrue
fan:falsetrue909
qqq:01234567890"""

print(re.sub(r"^.*:(.{0,7}|((?!.*(?!\d)\w)|(?!.*\d)).*)\r?$\n?", "", s, flags=re.M))
```

Comment: `console.log` это же вроде из Javascript'а?

Comment: Я  думаю, это сделано чтобы показать пример вывода, тут из концептуального только регулярка.

Comment: @ВладиславХарламов, тут еще постараться надо, чтобы преобразовать этот RegEx в такой, который будет правильно работать в Python ;)

Comment: @MaxU, что не так с регуляркой? Вроде ничего особенного не использовал.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если бы я знал что не так я бы смог сам исправить ;)

Comment: @MaxU, ты регулярку к каждой строке отдельно применяешь? Тогда убери `^` и `$`. UPDATE: А, не, не получится)

Comment: @MaxU, готово, опитонил.